# How to clear TFS Cache in a linux machine

Tags: jenkins, tfs

After removal of existing account all the workspaes for old account was deleted in my linux Jenkins server. But when changed configuration to new Account credentials. I am finding old workspaces could not be overrided with new account details. where on server side we could not find that workspace details.

Is there a way we can clear linux client cache?

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thanks for your answer. I tried to do the same as suggested. It doesn't work for me as the old account was removed totally and its work spaces mappings from TFS server. Not sure how the client on Linux still shows them mapped. So in my case I had two options 1. changed all my folders by changing JOB names and created workspaces with new user name. 2. Delete the folder contents "/var/lib/jenkins/.microsoft/Team Foundation". where if i deleted this folder contents jenkins lets me map the existing folders to be remapped with new user account.

Comment: Hi Ramakrishna, thanks for the sharing, since your issue solved, you could move your solution from  comment to the answer, and mark it,  which will also helps others in the community.

Answer (score -1):

According to my understand, seems you want to migrate all workspaces from your old user to another user. This can be accomplished by command line tool `tf.exe`

```
tf workspaces /updateUserName:OldUserName /collection:collectionurl
```

This should be done with your new account, and will **assign all workspaces from old account to current account**.

> ***/updateUserName***
>
> Updates security identification information on the Team Foundation
>   server for a user whose network user name has been changed. If you
>   specify this option, you must also specify a team project collection
>   by using the /collection option.

More details please refer  [Workspaces Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/workspaces-command?view=vsts) For Linux machine, you could use Team Explorer Everywhere (TEE) an Eclipse plug-in and a command-line client to run the command.

Another way is creating the server workspace on Windows, then use the /template option on Linux to setup the same configuration.